# Is ofstream thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working on a program, which uses multiple `std::ifstream`s for reading a binary file, one `std::ifstream` for each thread. Now I need to know, if `std::ofstream` is thread-safe on Windows and Linux for writing in a same file. I am using using only one `std::ofstream` and using for multiple threads.
I am reading different blocks using using each thread and writing those block in output file using `seekp()` and `write()`. Currently it is working for me but whether it is problematic for big files.

Is `std::ofstream` thread safe?

Comment: Please see the following it will be helpful

Please go through this 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754303/is-stdifstream-thread-safe-lock-free

Comment: *iostream* classes are an exception. It is safe to write to an object from multiple threads.If you don't mind that "this can result in the output from the two threads being intermixed."

Comment: Also see [How to easily make std::cout thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14718124/1468366)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [C++ standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2760.htm) (Input/Output Library Thread Safety):

> 27.1.3 Thread safety [iostreams.thread-safety]
>
> Concurrent access to a stream object [string.streams, file.streams], stream buffer object
>   [stream.buffers], or C Library stream [c.files] by multiple threads may result in a data 
>   race [intro.multithread] unless otherwise specified [iostream.objects]. [Note: Data races 
>   result in undefined behavior [intro.multithread].

Comment: How do you translate this part "unless otherwise specified [iostream.objects]..."?

Comment: It means that you cannot assume "per-se" that IO library is thread-safe (it may depend on implementation).

Answer (score 11):

If I haven't misunderstood you - no, nothing in the standard library is thread safe (except the `std::thread` specific things, of course (from C++11 and later)). You need additional synchronization.

Even more - if there are several processes, reading from/writing to these files, you need to lock the files, to sync the access.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, if I access (read/write) *differen* files at the same time, should I expect any problem?

Comment: @ransh - no, if the files are different and the streams are different, there will be no problems.

Comment: Actually - as far as I know - writing to cout is thread safe - the letters might get mixed however

Comment: If fwrite is not thread safe, why there is a "fwrite_unlocked" function in glibc ?

Comment: @ChangmingSun - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685115/does-fwrite-call-any-lock-internally

Answer (score 2):

I have written a little program to verify the thread-safety of `std::ifstream`
and `std::ofstream` https://github.com/rmspacefish/rpi-file-concurrency . I have tested with on a Linux Desktop host and a Raspberry Pi. The program starts two threads, one writer thread and one reader thread and there is a textual mode and a binary mode.

In the textual mode, I am writing two lines in the writer thread, and the reader thread attempts to read two lines. For the textual mode, I get the following output:

```
Concurrent file access test
Write Open Fail Count: 0
Write Count: 191090
Write Fail Count: 0

Read Open Fail Count: 0
Read Count: 93253
Read One Line Count: 93253
Read Both Lines Count: 93253
Faulty Read Count: 0
EOF Count: 0
Fail Count: 0

Finished.
```

So this appears to be thread-safe for Linux. For the binary mode, I am writing a binary block in form of a struct consisting of multiple fields like char arrays, integers with various sizes etc. I have two states which are written in alternating cycles. In the reader thread, I check the consistency of the data (inconistent states or worse, wrong values). Here I get the following results

```
Concurrent file access test
Write Open Fail Count: 0
Write Count: 0
Write Fail Count: 0

Read Open Fail Count: 0
Read Count: 0
Blob in state one read: 25491
Blob in state two read: 24702
Blob in invalid state: 0
Faulty Read Count: 0
EOF Count: 91295
Fail Count: 91295

Finished.
```

I checked the error flags after calling `read` (and this is important). If there are no error flags, the state is read in a consistent manner. It looks thread-safe to me.

The thread-safety might still be implementation dependent, but at least for Linux/GCC, file access seems to be thread-safe. I will still test this with MSVC on Windows, but Microsoft specified this should be thread-safe as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is.

For Windows:
it is safe to write to fstream from multiple threads on windows. Please see the msdn document: [Thread Safety in the C++ Standard Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9ceah3b.aspx)

For Linux:
In short, it is. From the [document of libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_concurrency.html): "if your platform's C library is threadsafe, then your fstream I/O operations will be threadsafe at the lowest level". Is your platform's C library threadsafe? Yes. The POSIX standard requires that C stdio FILE* operations(such as fread/fwrite) are atomic, and glibc did so.

Comment: I'm using OpenMP to compute and output to the same `ofstream` from multiple threads. Unless I protect the output (`ofstream << "Result: " << value << endl`) with `#pragma omp critical`, _sometimes_ I get the lines garbled. Not often, but it happens... This is on RHEL6, with hand-built g++-8.1 and its own libstdc++

Comment: If you change your code to: std::ostringstream oss;  oss << "Result: " << value << "\n"; ofstream<< oss.str(); That would be fine.

Comment: Whether that works or not, the asker’s question was: “is `ofstream` thread-safe?”. Not “how do I deal with it being unsafe?”

Comment: Well, maybe I was wrong. I just found, on Linux ,at syscall level, it can't write more than 2GB bytes in a single call. So, if glibc has an internal lock around the file descriptor for this, then it should be fine. But I don't know the details. Will update this  answer later.

Comment: Well, I cannot follow your answer: The microsoft document, that you linked to, guarantees thread safety only for writing to the standard iostream objects `cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, `clog`, `wcin`, `wcout`, `wcerr` and `wclog`. So  writing to any other `std::ofstream` is generally NOT thread safe. In particular, the document even further warns, that reading from a stream buffer is actually considered an [unsafe] write, as the buffer position is updated.

Comment: Sorry but "*It is safe in Windows and GCC*" != "*Yes. It is*". Good to know though.