# about locking in fread/fwrite and called from different processes

Tags: c, linux, file, io, locking

It seems that in Linux C calls to `fread` and `fwrite` are locked as on man pages (`man fwrite`) some unlocked function there are mentioned (`unlocked_stdio`).

As fare are you are aware, are these locks valid across process or do they lock only within the same process?

Comment: afaik, the sentence you have quoted refers to multithreading

Comment: "*Locking*"? Which locking? Daring to cite our source of info?

Comment: added source. Unfortunately I 've also just found this post. Refers to Solaris but it mentions C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685115/does-fwrite-call-any-lock-internally

Answer (score 3):

They don't even lock within the process. They only lock the actual stream object on which you call them. If, for example, you have two `FILE*` objects that reference the same underlying file or terminal, `fread` and `fwrite` will happily allow them to trample each other, even in the same process.

Comment: ...oh dear... so the only guarantee here is that FILE* stream it will be intact (hopefully within the same process) but not the actual write on file which can be interleaved by other ops. So it's up the dev to make sure that the 2 are synch correctly..

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile Across processes, you can use `flock`-style locks. Within a process, well, you're writing all the code, so you should be able to find some way to do it.